# Codeigniter insert data from another table and add to input post

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a table that has a record of 1 row containing rates of products.
in second table, I have orders with name, email, contact number, cost.

what I want to do is, when customer save values to orders, the rates from ratestb will save to cost.

this is my current model which only adds to orderstb:

```
public function add($data)
  {
    $this->db->insert('orders', $data);
  }
```

this is my controller:

```
public function addOrder()
  {
    $this->Order_model->add($this->input->post(null, true));
  }
```

and my view is the fields name, email and number only.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the last inserted data by using $this->db->insert_id();

```
$this->db->insert('orders', $data);
$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

this will return the Primary key of your table "orders". You can fetch the data by executing the get query now.

```
$this->db->where('order_id', $insert_id);
$query = $this->db->get('orders');
```